# Does a save to a scss file automatically update the css file?

Tags: css, sass, webstorm

I just started working with scss a few days ago (with Webstorm), and it seem to auto generate/update the css file after saving the scss file. Unfortunately, when I save the scss file now, no changes are made to the css file. I was working on these files from a different location, so I am guessing that the Webstorm settings might be different. I thought file watchers might have something to do with it, but I am not sure what goes in the program field. I really have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, saving a `.SCSS` file does not automatically compile the final stylesheet file.  What you need to do is set up a watch.  There are a number of ways to do this (and a number of programs that'll do it for you).

The most straight forward is through the command line.  Assuming you have the SASS gem installed (and you're in a ruby environment), do the following in the command line:

1. Navigate to the folder in which your .scss file/s are kept.
2. Run the following command:  `sass --watch style.scss:style.css`

Note:  The above assumes that both your .scss and .css files are named *style*, adjust accordingly if they are not.  Also, if your .css and .scss files are in different directories you'll have to adjust the paths accordingly.

Remember, `sass --watch` then `yourScssFile.scss` : `yourCssFile.css`

Alternatively you can use an app, like [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) to watch the files for you.  this'll take a bit of configuration, but it may be a little easier for you if you're only just getting started in the wornderful world of SCSS/SASS

Comment: Can you suggest any programs that do this?

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer :)

Comment: This might also help (assuming you're on a mac) http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/internet-roundup/5-mac-apps-that-make-css-preprocessors-easier-to-use/

Comment: Using the command line would be nice, but I do not have SASS gem installed, and I do not know if I am in a ruby environment (unless these things come standard). Therefore, I think I am going to give LiveReload a shot. I think it is awesome that it also automatically refreshes the browser. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Good answer, explained well +1.

Comment: I managed to install gem via command line...but when I try to watch the changes,it says Sass  is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
But I do not see  any changes when I  go back to the website.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yopu can use File Watchers in WebStorm to auto-update the CSS file on changing SCSS; but this would also require installing the external SCSS compiler (SASS gem).  Please refer to http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d104715e458 for more information

Comment: The same goes with Jetbrain's PyCharm IDE. Creating or editing a SASS file will allow you to add a watcher very easily through a toolbar on top of the file editor.